# Bitrix - как лучше реализовать разные свойства для разных товаров?

Tags: битрикс

Как лучше сделать разные свойства товаров? Варианта вижу два:

1. настраивать по привязке к разделу;
2. сделать разные виды инфоблоков для каждой категории товара (т.е. есть инфоблок `компьютеры`, есть инфоблок `фотоаппараты` и т.п.)

Интересуют преимущества и недостатки обоих способов. Какой вариант будет быстрее работать? Какой удобнее настраивать? Буду благодарен за ваши мнения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Сможешь использовать для каталога один комплексный компонент. Работать будет "Из коробки". Свойства будут красиво разделены. Но при большом количестве свойств настройки инфоблока будут притормаживать.
2. Придется для каждого раздела подключать свой компонент и настраивать на соответствующий инфоблок. Скорее всего, возникнут проблемы с поиском по каталогу. Точно будут проблемы с выгрузкой в 1С (если когда-нибудь понадобится). Поддерживать такую реализацию будет сложно.